# Framebox and minipage causes white space and is not float

Tags: environments, page-breaking, framed

I have a \framebox (I don't insist on using this command) and a minipage that causes whitespace, because the drawn box is not allowing any text before or after and it itself does not break over pages. The code looks like this:

```
\framebox{%
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
    Title Goes Here
    \end{center}
    Contents go here
 \end{minipage} 
  }
```

Am I using the correct command? If so, how can I break it over pages? or if it is not possible to break it, I must give it a label and caption (just like a table or figure) and make it inline with text so that I can refer it in the article, but I don't know that either.

Comment: use package `mdframed`. See documentation on how it has to be used

Comment: Thanks. That's it. Would you please state it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Is there anything like it for blocks of math (I mean between two $, like $\phi^\rho$ and so). When such a block reaches end of line, it goes further to margins and I must correct it manually. Is there a way to correct it another way?

Comment: I don't get "the drawn box is not allowing any text before or after". This is not the behaviour of `\framebox`.

Comment: I mean the box is larger than half of the page, and it causes the previous page to have white spaces. and it starts at the beginning of next page.

Comment: @Yasser: I see. You can turn it into a float using the `float` package or just push it to the top of the next page without interrupting the page by putting it into `\afterpage{...}` from the `afterpage` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you can also give a try is this code from the `memoir` manual for a `framed` environment with a caption. It can break across pages and gives a continuation caption. It can also be referred to with a `\ref`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{framed}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\framename{Frame}
\newcounter{framecnt}
\setcounter{framecnt}{0}
\newcommand{\TitleFrame}[2]{%
    \fboxrule=\FrameRule
    \fboxsep=\FrameSep
    \vbox{\nobreak \vskip -0.7\FrameSep
        \rlap{\strut#1}\nobreak\nointerlineskip% left justified
        \vskip 0.7\FrameSep
        \noindent\fbox{#2}}}
\newenvironment{titledframe}[2][\FrameFirst@Lab\ (cont.)]{%
    \refstepcounter{framecnt}%
    \def\FrameFirst@Lab{\textbf{\framename\ \theframecnt:\ #2}}%
    \def\FrameCont@Lab{\textbf{#1}}%
    \def\FrameCommand##1{%
        \TitleFrame{\FrameFirst@Lab}{##1}}%
    \def\FirstFrameCommand##1{%
        \TitleFrame{\FrameFirst@Lab}{##1}}%
    \def\MidFrameCommand##1{%
        \TitleFrame{\FrameCont@Lab}{##1}}%
    \def\LastFrameCommand##1{%
        \TitleFrame{\FrameCont@Lab}{##1}}%
    \MakeFramed{\hsize\textwidth
    \advance\hsize -2\FrameRule
    \advance\hsize -2\FrameSep
    \FrameRestore}}%
   {\endMakeFramed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{titledframe}{A titled frame}\label{frm:A}
      \blindtext[6]
    \end{titledframe}

    \begin{titledframe}{A New frame}\label{frm:B}
      \blindtext[1]
    \end{titledframe}
    In frames~\ref{frm:A} and \ref{frm:B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know anything for formulae, is it possible to have an script or so t automatically break the formula to the next line when it is exceeding the usual length and entering the margin?

Comment: @Yasser Sobhdel: No unfortunately not. There are a lot of rules regarding where to break a single equation into multi-line ones. I think it is very close to impossible to automate that.