# Splitting Frames into Multiple Columns

Tags: boxes

I am working on a document, which uses multicolumns. I am also using several boxes (Minipage, Simple frame) as well. The problem is: everytime a box -which is near to the end of a column- doesn't fit in that column where it has to be, Lyx automatically transfers it to the next column and leaves the previous column with a huge gap. Is there any way to prevent this by splitting the frames?

Comment: I think this is related to the following issue: [tex.se](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19099/framebox-and-minipage-causes-white-space-and-is-not-float)

Comment: the documentation of mdframed says that it isn’t possible to use the multicolumn environment =( -package "framed" doesnt work either-

Comment: I think that then there is no "easy" solution for your problem. One thing might help: not using frames, but groups with other formatting could be a workaround.

Comment: `mdfamed` and `multicol` save the contents in a savebox and split them. The new version is able to work with two column. The algorithm isn't compatible.

Comment: nice, but I have 4 of them (it's a cheatsheet).

Comment: Would you be able to reproduce the problem in a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that reproduces the problem? Including a link to an image of what the problematic output looks like would also help with suggestions of how to solve the problem.

Comment: If (as seems likely) this question gets closed, it's just a way of indicating to casual passers-by that we don't yet have enough information to help you.  If you edit your question to include an MWE (as Werner suggests), and/or explain more carefully what you are trying to do (as it seems quite specialised) then we may be able to help you find a solution.  As it is, it's hard to tell what would help so the question will (probably) be closed until we can get some clarification.